# Linux - real root vs normal root

Tags: linux, unix

Is there such a thing as a normal root and a real root in Unix/Linux?

I am doing a buffer overflow project (in Ubuntu 11.04) and I invoke /bin/zsh and /bin/bash separately. In both cases

`$whoami` returns root

`$id` returns uid=1000, euid=0, gid=1000.

But, when I try to run

```
$passwd username
```

to change some user's password, the shell returns:

```
passwd: You may not view or modify password information for username
```

Is there something that I am missing here as I believe this is root does not have low level privileges. I have searched all over the net, but I don't seem to find a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, commands such as $useradd, $userdel, $chown work without any elevation

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean "real UID / GID" vs "effective UID / GID" ..?

**real UID** : this is the UID of the process that created THIS process - e.g. as who you logged in.

**effective UID**: This UID is used to evaluate privileges of the process to perform actions.

you should **check here**:

http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node23.html

http://mahmudonline.com/?p=278

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

http://en.allexperts.com/q/Unix-Linux-OS-1064/real-effective-user-id.htm

---

EDIT:

Just found this page, which has a nice description:

http://bashscript.blogspot.com/2010/03/unixlinux-advanced-file-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I understand what real and effective UID/GID mean, but my question is why does the real UID not become zero when I invoke /bin/bash or /bin/zsh from some buffer overflow vulnerable program?

Rather effective UID is made zero.

I forgot to mention that my motive is to obtain real UID to be zero without running a separate shell code that sets real uid = 0 (with setuid(0)).

Comment: @Suchit: If that is what your question is, you could either update your question or ask a new one.